# New accesstoken. Always unauthenticate even if I replcaed session_key & sig

Tags: ios, facebook-chat

According to chat doc:

```
 // creates the response array

  $resp_array = array(

    'method' => $challenge_array['method'],

    'nonce' => $challenge_array['nonce'],

    'access_token' => $access_token,

    'api_key' => $options['app_id'],

    'call_id' => 0,

    'v' => '1.0',
  );
  // creates signature

  $response = http_build_query($resp_array);
```

So I change my code below:

```
[buffer appendFormat:@"api_key=%@&", self.app_key];
[buffer appendFormat:@"call_id=%d&", rand()];
[buffer appendFormat:@"method=%@&", self.method];
[buffer appendFormat:@"nonce=%@&", self.nonce];
[buffer appendFormat:@"access_token=%@&",self.accessToken];
[buffer appendFormat:@"v=%@&",@"1.0"];
NSData *utf8data = [buffer dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then send `[utf8data base64Encoded]` to fb server

But still obtain unauthentication error.

```
RECV: <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>
```

Obviously, I replaced the session_key & sig with accesstoken.

Did I omit something?

I do not know how to kill this trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're also using TLS.  In the PHP code example:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/  you'll see how this is handled if you search for $START_TLS